# Ajax Retornando todo HTML da página

Tags: html, ajax, json

Tenho uma requisição AJAX no site de um cliente na página do produto, que ao selecionar o tamanho disponível do produto ele altera o preço, porém no retorno do AJAX ao invés de pegar somente o preço ele pega todo o HTML da página, ou seja ele carrega a página toda com o preço alterado. O que eu quero é pegar somente o preço.

Acredito que seja conflito com a URL amigável, não sei ao certo, já tentei de tudo, inclusive tentei puxar os dados via JSON mais não funciona.

Qual seria a causa desse problema?

Comment: Pode postar seu código? Qual ferramenta você usa? Use o botão de   editar
http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/136042/edit pra acrescentar mais detalhes.

Comment: Itallo, poste o fonte para nos ajudar a te ajudar :) Dica: Na requisição Ajax verifique o datatype que você esta usando. http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp

Comment: Pode ser que tenha um include do cabeçalho onde é processada a requisição ajax, poste o código fonte que está trabalhando para termos mais detalhes...

Answer (score 1):

Você pode pegar apenas o conteúdo de uma `div` específica no retorno do Ajax.

Por exemplo, suponha que na página em que está tenha uma `div` com `id` `#preco` com o valor de **R$ 100,00**:

```
<div id="preco">
    R$ 100,00
</div
```

Agora você quer pegar o novo valor que retorna do Ajax e ele está retornando todo o HTML da página, mas você só quer o conteúdo da `div` `#preco` para atualizar na página em que está. Digamos que retorne o HTML abaixo no Ajax:

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
     <h1>Bla Bla</h1>
     <div id="preco">R$ 200,00</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Você quer pegar o valor que está na `div` `#preco` do HTML (**R$ 200,00**) retornado e jogar na `div` `#preco` da página atual. Para isto, você pode usar o código abaixo em JavaScript puro:

```
var http = false;
http = new XMLHttpRequest();

var url_="pagina.php";
http.open("GET",url_,true);
http.onreadystatechange=function(){
   if(http.readyState==4){
      var html = http.responseText;
      var html = new DOMParser().parseFromString(html, "text/html");
      document.getElementById('preco_original').innerHTML = html.getElementById('preco').innerHTML.trim();
   }
}
http.send(null);
```

**Ou em jQuery:**

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'pagina.php',
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(html) {
        $("#preco").html($(html).filter('#preco').text().trim());
    }
});
```