# Requisição AJAX retornando toda a página HTML

Tags: php

Estou utilizando uma função ajax que retorna algo para min, mas a mesma função além de me retornar o resultado esperado, ela retorna todo o código HTML da página.

No meu formulário de login eu utilizo a função ajax para autenticar, e eu recebo o código HTML da página como retorno, mas se eu utilizo o post do formulário o resultado esperado é retornado sem o código HTML da página.

Segue o código:

**login.php**

```
<?php 
    require_once '../../vendor/autoload.php';
    require_once '../route/routes.php';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>AdminLTE 2 | Log in</title>
  <!-- Tell the browser to be responsive to screen width -->
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
  <!-- Bootstrap 3.3.7 -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../assets/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <!-- Font Awesome -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../assets/bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <!-- Ionicons -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../assets/bower_components/Ionicons/css/ionicons.min.css">
  <!-- Theme style -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../assets/css/AdminLTE.min.css">
  <script src="../../assets/js/requisicao-ajax-view.js"></script>

  <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
  <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->

  <!-- Google Font -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,600,700,300italic,400italic,600italic">
</head>
<body class="hold-transition login-page">
<div class="login-box">
  <div class="login-logo">

  </div>
  <!-- /.login-logo -->
  <div class="login-box-body">
    <p class="login-box-msg">Faça login para acessar o sistema</p>

      <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Login" id="login" name="login">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope form-control-feedback"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Senha" id="senha" name="senha">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock form-control-feedback"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-8">
          <div class="checkbox icheck">

          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.col -->
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat" onclick="requisicaoAjaxAutenticaUsuario();">Entrar</button>
        </div>
        <!-- /.col -->
      </div>

    <a href="#">Esqueci minha senha</a><br>
    <a href="register.html" class="text-center">Registrar-se</a>

  </div>
  <!-- /.login-box-body -->
</div>
<!-- /.login-box -->

<!-- jQuery 3 -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap 3.3.7 -->
<script src="../../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- iCheck -->
<script src="../../plugins/iCheck/icheck.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function () {
    $('input').iCheck({
      checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_square-blue',
      radioClass: 'iradio_square-blue',
      increaseArea: '20%' // optional
    });
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**funcao-ajax-autentica.js**

```
     function requisicaoAjaxAutenticaUsuario(){
            //RECUPERA OS DADOS DO FORM DE LOGIN
            var login = document.getElementById("login").value;
            var senha = document.getElementById("senha").value;

            if(login.length > 0 && senha.length > 0){
                $.ajax({
                    type:'post',
                    data:{login: login, senha: senha},
                    contenttype: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: 'login.php/usuario/autentica',
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert(data);
                    },
                    error: function (erro) {
                        console.log(erro);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
```

**routes.php**

```
$app = new Slim\App;

$app->post('/usuario/autentica', function($request){
    $login = $request->getParsedBody()['login'];
    $senha = $request->getParsedBody()['senha'];

    require'../model/usuario.php';
    $autentica = new App\Model\Usuario;
    echo $autentica->autenticaUsuario($login, $senha);

});
$app->run();
```

**usuario.class.php**

```
<?php
namespace App\Model;

/**
 * Classe com os metodos dos usuarios
 *
 * @author Abner Marques
 */
class Usuario {

    public function autenticaUsuario($login, $senha){
        echo $login;
    }
}
```

O código que é retornado é esse:

eu dou um `alert`, e no começo do código a letra A é o valor que eu insiro no campo de login, esta retornando normalmente, mas o que está de errado é o retorno do código HTML da página.

[image: eu dou um alert, e no começo do código a letra A é o valor que eu insiro no campo de login, esta retoornando normalmente, mas o que está de errado é o retorno do código HTML da página.]

Comment: estou usando o sistemas de rotas do slim framework

Comment: routes.php

$app = new Slim\App;

$app->get('/', function(){
    
});

$app->post('/usuario/autentica', function($request){
    $login = $request->getParsedBody()['login'];
    $senha = $request->getParsedBody()['senha'];
    
    require'../model/usuario.php';
    $autentica = new App\Model\Usuario;
    echo $autentica->autenticaUsuario($login, $senha);
    
});
$app->run();

usuarios.class.php

<?php

class Usuario {
    
    public function autenticaUsuario($login, $senha){
        echo $login;
    }
}

Comment: segue o codigo.

Comment: acabei de editar, desculpe sou novo no forum

Comment: Suas rotas estão definidas no arquivo `routes.php`, mas você faz a requisição para `login.php`. Isso está certo?

Comment: Sim esta correto, as rotas estão funcionando corretamente.
Eu faço a requisição para a rota desejada, o arquivo de rotas está incluido no arquivo php do formulario de autenticação do usuário

Comment: Que confusão. Qual, então, é o código do arquivo `login.php`? Já adianto para você fazer o [tour] pelo site e ler urgentemente o guia de [ask]. Tente fornecer na pergunta **todos os detalhes** referente ao problema, senão será impossível inferir qualquer coisa.

Comment: ja postei o codigo do login.php, no evento onclick do botao do form de login, eu champo a função ajax de login, nela eu capturo os dados do form e envio para a rota que eu instancio a classe usuario e chamo o metodo de autenticação do usuário, e no metodo eu retorno pro ajax o login do usuário.

Comment: Pronto. Problema resolvido. Olha o HTML retornado ali no `login.php`. Tudo o que estiver dentro desse arquivo será retornado para o JavaScript.

Comment: mas esse é a página que o usuário irá fazer o login, ela deve existir.

Comment: Acredito que você não entendeu muita coisa básica do processo e por isso está essa confusão. Pela lógica, o arquivo `routes.php` não deveria estar incluído no `login.php`; isso não faz muito sentido. O Slim, em tese, deveria receber todas as requisições através do arquivo `routes.php` e ele que definir o que deveria ser retornado ao cliente, inclusive os códigos HTML. Muita coisa aí parece que seria resolvido corretamente somente refatorando o projeto, o que é impossível fazer pelo site. Então recomendo que leia mais sobre o Slim e busque entender melhor como o protocolo HTTP funciona.

Comment: Talvez esta resposta possa ser aplicada na sua pergunta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/259599/8063

Answer (score 1):

Como você fez uma requisição ajax, qualquer coisa que você montar no seu back-end (por exemplo um echo no php) vai voltar para sua variável de resposta do ajax. O que você tem que fazer é redirecionar o usuário caso ele tenha feito o login com sucesso. Eu por exemplo sempre volto um "logado" para o javascript.

```
success: function (data) {
    if(data == 'logado'){
        window.location.replace(url);
    }
},
```

Na url que eu faço o redirecionamento tem um código que verifica se o usuário está realmente logado, redirecionando ele para a área restrita do site ou voltando para a página de login.

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que seu problema esteja sendo causado devido seu código de saída não estar sendo finalizado ao final da requisição `ajax`; Após seus `echo` seria necessário algo como `return` ou `exit` (dependendo do seu php), então ficaria algo como:

**routes.php**

```
$app = new Slim\App;

$app->post('/usuario/autentica', function($request){
    $login = $request->getParsedBody()['login'];
    $senha = $request->getParsedBody()['senha'];

    require'../model/usuario.php';
    $autentica = new App\Model\Usuario;
    echo $autentica->autenticaUsuario($login, $senha);
    return;
});
$app->run();
```

**usuario.class.php**

```
namespace App\Model;

/**
 * Classe com os metodos dos usuarios
 *
 * @author Abner Marques
 */
class Usuario {

    public function autenticaUsuario($login, $senha){
        return $login;
    }
}
```

E como o @Phelipe falou, seria interessante controlar melhor o retorno do `php` e tratamento no `ajax`, tente trabalhar nesse caso do login com falso e verdade (logado ou falhou o login). Tratando os dados devidamente o retorno como `JSON`.

Answer (score -3):

estou usando o sistemas de rotas do slim framework, a requisicao ajax manda para esta rota login.php/usuario/autentica, e einstancia a classe usuario e chama o metodo de autenticação,

routes.php

```
$app = new Slim\App;

$app->post('/usuario/autentica', function($request){
    $login = $request->getParsedBody()['login'];
    $senha = $request->getParsedBody()['senha'];

    require'../model/usuario.php';
    $autentica = new App\Model\Usuario;
    echo $autentica->autenticaUsuario($login, $senha);

});
$app->run();
```

usuario.class.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Model;

/**
 * Classe com os metodos dos usuarios
 *
 * @author Abner Marques
 */
class Usuario {

    public function autenticaUsuario($login, $senha){
        echo $login;
    }
}
```

era pra ele retornar apenas o login do usuario, mas ele esta retornando o login junto o codigo da pagina html

Comment: Abaixo da pergunta há o botão [edit]. Está área é exclusiva para respostas.

Comment: Aproveite e já coloque qual é o código HTML retornado também.